# Multiple Transactions in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any risk to call beginTransaction on one session multiple times? I mean for example:

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(object1);
// .... some works
session.beginTransaction();
session.delete(object2);
// ... some other works
session.getTransaction.commit();
```

I did this and it seems there is no problem (any exception or warning). In fact I want to know what happens when I use transaction in such a way.

Comment: Even if it works, it shows a design problem in your application and make things very confusing.

Comment: @JB-Nizet I use getCurrentSession to get the session and I told Hibernate to get current session thread-widely. Because my threads may (or may not do) many works in many methods, I want to be sure about beginning of transactions. I will commit all the work in the end of the thread execution.

Comment: If these objects have a relationship then just set a CascadeType on the relationship to do what you need, or else you can use the EntityManager implementation instead of using session directly, that way in one transaction you can tell it to persist, update,delete whatever.

Comment: Related: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=929449&highlight=nested+transaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction%28%29) give an explanation

> `beginTransaction()` Begin a unit of work and return the associated Transaction object. **If a new underlying transaction is required, begin the transaction. Otherwise continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction**. The class of the returned Transaction object is determined by the property hibernate.transaction_factory.

So - it has no effect, it continues using the existing transaction. So don't do it, as it might confuse readers (including you). You can have multiple transactions if you commit the first and then start the second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There wont be any compile/run time exceptions thrown. However there are undesired results that might come up, resulting in the partly unsaved data. I have faced this issues sometime back.

Comment: how come? There won't be any unexpected results. Check my answer.

Comment: Nested transactions are not supported by database vendors. The JTA spec gets around it by suspending a transaction (throught the TransactionManager interface) to allow another Tx to be used. Hibernate can emulate this in JDBC Tx mode.

Comment: JTA - perhaps, but hibernate explicitly states that it doesn't do anything 'funky' and simply continues to use the same transaction

Comment: Hibernate uses JDBC (or JTA) transactions, they can not be nested. What you need is an "application transaction" that spans multiple database transactions. Have a look at optimistic concurrency control and automatic version checking in the documentation

Comment: so, you copy-pasted that comment from the hibernate forum? :)

Comment: Yes. Because it answered the question.

Comment: sure. I pasted the link as comment to the question (quoting sources is a good thing)